How does query a user whose "status" attribute value is 1 in OpenLDAP?
All users have  "status" attribute, it vaule is 0 or 1.
How does query user whose ldap "status" attribute value is 1 ?
OpenLDAP slapd 2.4.48.
I tried the following but it didn't work:
# ldapsearch -x -H ldap://lda-server -b "ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn" "(&(objectClass=person)(status=*))"
 
# 2012010497, staff, people, sso.gdu.com
dn: uid=2012010497,ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn
lastTime:: MjAyM+W5tDfmnIgyNeaXpSDkuIvljYgxMuaXtjA05YiGNTXnp5I=
sn:: Jack
roleId: 3
status: 1
roleName:: Engineer
gid: 051
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: sperson
uid: 208010188
cn:: Lin
userPassword:: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# search result
search: 2
result: 4 Size limit exceeded

# numResponses: 501
# numEntries: 500

[root@localhost /]## ldapsearch -x -H ldap://lda-server -b "ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn" "(&(objectClass=person)(status=1))"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectClass=person)(status=1))
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
[root@localhost /]## ldapsearch -x -H ldap://lda-server -b "ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn" "(&(objectClass=person)(status=0))"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectClass=person)(status=0))
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

The schema definition of status:
attributetype ( 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.3.8 NAME 'status'
                DESC 'status'
                SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
                SINGLE-VALUE )


What was the schema definition of this attribute – does it have an EQUALITY match defined?

(...and also, why is the server set up such that userPassword data is visible to any unauthenticated client??)

I has been added the schema definition of status to the question.
@u1686_grawity, thanks you reply!

Every custom LDAP attribute must have matching rules defined explicitly, as part of the schema. When doing a (status=1) search, the values are compared according to the EQUALITY matching rule – e.g. basic case-sensitive string match, or case-ignore match, or integer match, or more specialized rules such as DN match or timestamp match.
If the schema entry doesn't define matching rules, then regular filters that try to match against the attribute just won't work, as there is no default so the directory server doesn't know how to handle the value. (The whole thing comes from X.500, which was all about strongly-typed protocols and formats.)
Your attribute is defined as a Unicode string, so if you're able to update the schema, you should add equality (and perhaps also substring) rules suitable for strings:

attributetype ( 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.3.8 NAME 'status'
                DESC 'status'
                SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
                EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
                SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
                SINGLE-VALUE )

…or with caseExact[Substring]Match if that's more suitable for you. After schema update you should probably trigger a reindex using slapindex.
(Side note: Even though it doesn't matter to LDAP, get a real OID branch registered. It's free.)
If the schema cannot be updated in time, you can try to use a filter like this to force the use of a specific matching rule (see the earlier "Matching rules" link for a more extensive list of options):
(status:integerMatch:=1)
(status:caseExactMatch:=1)

(status:2.5.13.14:=1)             -- integerMatch
(status:2.5.13.5:=1)              -- caseExactMatch
(status:2.5.13.2:=1)              -- caseIgnoreMatch

So, for example:
ldapsearch -H ldap://lda-server -x \
           -b "ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sso,dc=gdu,dc=cn" \
           "(&(objectClass=person)(status:2.5.13.5:=1))"

But this should be considered a "last resort" option – not the normal way you operate LDAP, but rather the way you operate LDAP while you're waiting for the server configuration to be fixed.
(On a related note, lastTime really should have been defined as a generalizedTime attribute using LDAP standard timestamp formats – that would then have made it possible to use >= filters with it, etc.)
